# Rhino Mock Verify that a Mehods was Called Many Times in a Particular Order

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a

I have an Interface called IFileDownloader which has a signature called DownlowadFile(string url, string fileName)

I have a class, called, StockManager which implements this method. This class has another method called DownloadFiles(string url, String[] fileNames) which calls the Interface method. How can I use Rhino Mocks to verify that the signature was called for each of the passed file in the String[] fileNames?

I have implemented it for a single file but unsure how to modify it to take an ordered list? Here is my sample code:

```
var stubbedFileDownloader = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFileDownloader>();
string url = "http://abc.def.klm/download/"
string EXPECTED_FILENAME = "AVC2.xml";
stubbedFileDownloader.Stub(x => x.DownloadFile(url, EXPECTED_FILENAME)
    .Return(true);

var stockManager = new StockManager();   
stockManager.DownloadFiles(url, new string[] { "AVC2.xml" } );
stubbedFileDownloader.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, not that if you use `.Stub` you only specify behavior. It does not record an expectation. To record an expectation which is checked by `VerifyAllExpectations`, use `.Expect` instead of `.Stub`.

When you use `.Expect` for multiple calls with different arguments, then `VerifyAllExpectations` will check that they were called in the given order.